# Is it possible to get a pointer to two different frames in a video sequence at the same time with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

You can access a specific frame in a video sequence like this:

```
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_num);
capture >> frame;
```

You can then access a separate frame like this:

```
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_num - 20);
capture >> frame2;
```

However, when you set the capture property with `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`, it actually moves the first pointer and `frame` and `frame2` end up pointing to the same data, containing the same values.

I want a pointer to both, so I do not have to clone the data (expensive computation) but I can perform comparisons between the two frames.  How can this be done with OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a copy of the first frame:

```
Mat frame1 = frame.clone();
```

Comment: Yup.  That is noted in the very last paragraph.  Cloning several times on a very large matrix gets expensive, so I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Anyway you need a copy somewhere - in your code or inside the OpenCV.

Comment: Well when i do capture >> frame, isn't it just a pointer into the video file at that particular frame?  So if I could get two of those... Because I need to set that pointer twice either way.  It's unnecessary overhead

Comment: No, it is not. Normally frames inside a video file are compressed/encoded and getting pointer is not possible at all.